# IRegistrationConvention structuremap CtorDependency

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

I need to send a custom instance in Ctor in scanner. Hear is my code:

```
public class RunnableScanner : IRegistrationConvention
    {
        private readonly List<Module> modules; 
        public RunnableScanner()
        {
            var config = RegisterModulesConfig.GetConfig();
            modules = config.Modules.ToList();
        }

        public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
        {
            if (!type.IsAbstract && typeof(IRunnable).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            {
                var module = modules.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == type.Name);
                if (module != null)
                {
                    registry.For(typeof (IRunnable)).Use(type).Named(type.Name).CtorDependency<Scheduler>("scheduler")
                    .IsNamedInstance(module.Scheduler + "Scheduler");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the line :

```
registry.For(typeof (IRunnable)).Use(type).Named(type.Name).CtorDependency<Scheduler>("scheduler")             .IsNamedInstance(module.Scheduler + "Scheduler");
```

i need to set a value for Scheduler ("Interval" property).

I did try this:

```
var sch = ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<Scheduler>(module.Scheduler + "Scheduler");
                    sch.Interval = module.Interval;
                    registry.For(typeof (IRunnable)).Use(type).Named(type.Name).CtorDependency<Scheduler>("scheduler").Is(sch);
```

but this don't work because ObjectFactory i cant use in Registry.

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a structuremap expert so maybe this is not the best/most elegant/effective solution.

But the following registration using a `LambdaInstance` seems to work

```
registry.For(typeof (IRunnable)).Use(type).Named(type.Name)
        .CtorDependency<Scheduler>("scheduler")
        .Is(new LambdaInstance<Scheduler>(c =>
          {
              var sch = c.GetInstance<Scheduler>(module.Scheduler + "Scheduler");
              sch.Interval = module.Interval;
              return sch;
          })
    );
```

Comment: I think you can leave out the `new LambdaInstance<Scheduler>(` part and just pass in the lambda to the `Is` method. Other than that I think it looks perfect.